# How do I do WHERE ‘OR’ and “AND’ with DBIx:Class?

Tags: sql, perl, orm, dbix-class

How can I do the equivalent with DBIx::Class search or find?

```
SELECT * 
FROM `person` 
WHERE ( `name` = 'doug' OR `nickname` = 'doug' ) AND `age` = 50;
```

I've searched the documentation but I don't seem to be able to work it out. I've tried the following but I cannot get it to work.

```
my $result  = $db->resultset('person')->find(
   {  [ { name => 'doug',  nickname => 'doug' } ] , age =>  50  }  
)};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, I think I worked it out

```
my $ingress  = $db->resultset('person')->search(
{  -and => [
     -or => [
            name => 'doug' ,
            nickname => 'doug' ],
           age => 50 ] },
```

Comment: The first parameter to `search` can also be an arrayref so you can shorten your code by passing `[ -or => {}, age => 50 ]` to it.

Comment: Thanks abraxxa, I originally tried that but the sql created saw the array as the table name in the where clause :s

Comment: The table name can never end up in the where clause, please post your search and the generated SQL.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it appears I was missing the '-or' when I originally tried it.